# Codeigniter Custom Routing showing root site background image?

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-url

Ok, so I have a project I'm working on:  http://www.d2burke.com/exp/intern/

BaseURL is set to:  '/exp/intern/'

.htaccess reroutes to /exp/intern/index.php

I have custom routes set up for

1. http://www.d2burke.com/exp/intern/questions
   -- `$route['apply'] = "internship/apply";`
2. http://www.d2burke.com/exp/intern/apply
   -- `$route['questions'] = "internship/questions";`

etc.

When you go to http://www.d2burke.com/exp/intern/internship/questions, all is well and the normal tan background shows up...

When you use one of the custom routes...you get the background image from my main site...? what is the world is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to overwrite the background by loading an extra style sheet in the body content like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" />
```

The browser interprets this as a *relative path to your page path.*

In the internship/questions page, this relative page translate to http://www.d2burke.com/exp/css/style.css, which doesn't exists.

The fix would be to use an absolute path like /css/style.css

Note: It's pretty obvious if you use Firebug and check the Net tab

**EDIT:** Alternatively, open Firebug, click the arrow in the Console tab and enable "Show Network Error". That way any 404 error will appear in your console and come up as an error (great debug feature)

Comment: Thanks for the response Ben, but a few quesitons from here:

where do you see the additional stylesheet load attempt?  I don't see that.  Also, if the page weren't finding 'style.css' at /exp/intern/css/style.css...then why does it load any css styles at all?

Comment: @d2burke. Re: Additional style sheet: Search the source code of the rendered page for .css, you'll see there's the additional style sheet mentioned in my post loaded. (just after "CONTENT GOES BELOW THIS POINT")

Comment: @d2burke. Re: Any CSS at all. The other style sheets (the one in the head section) are absolute path'ed (/exp/intern/css/...), so the path is always valid

Comment: @d2burke. Also see my post edit about turning on Network Errors in firebug, it's really useful.

Comment: Well, well...don't i feel foolish.  I put that there a while back for local testing.  This post should explode.  Thank you for your patience and my apologies for wasting your time with something so silly